# Since v3.0 Facebook Graph API group-id/feed endpoint always returns empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small FB app which were retrieving posts from a group where I am an admin. It was working fine for ages, but with the latest changes in v3.0 of the Graph API, it is broken, and I totally don't understand why.

My access token has `groups_access_member_info,user_managed_groups` permission and I able to see my SECRET group in the list `GET /v3.0/me/groups`

However, when I try to retrieve the feed `GET /v3.0/<group-id>/feed` the empty list is returned.
I also tried to do it for the CLOSED group and the result is the same.

What happened? Is it FB bug? Did anybody managed to retrieve feed from a group?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4 - you need to get your app reviewed for access to Groups API. Until you do, it will only work as long as your app is in dev mode.

Comment: ok, I have no probs with dev mode, however how about Graph API explorer? the behaviour reproduces their perfectly. Is it also not approved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm have the same question as well. Facebook and others keep telling us to use our own app, but we just use Graph API explorer to download group posts. We are a university study research group, not a startup or a company so we don't have our own app to give people.

Comment: Well, it's not so difficult to create your own app, but that won't make broken feed api work...

Answer (score 1):

Your app must be be approved for the [Groups API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/) feature. 
The Groups API is a collection of Graph API endpoints that let you read and create Facebook Group data on behalf of group members.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I didn't know that. I'll check it out!